# how to return an XML attribute using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to return the name of the test in the following XML file:

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<robot rpa="false" generated="20190905 22:17:06.914" 
generator="Robot 3.1.2">
<suite source="test.xml" id="s1" name="testXML">
<test id="s1-t1" name="[TC000] TEST 000">
</test>
<test id="s1-t2" name="[TC001] TEST 001">
</test>
</suite>
</robot>
XML;
```

I've tried to target the parent element test with the following php code:

```
<?php include 'log.php';
$robot = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
foreach ($robot->test as $name) {
echo $name->name, PHP_EOL;
} ?>
```

I'd like to echo the test name [TC000] TEST 000

Comment: Test is inside suite.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 4

Comment: And if suite[0]->test?

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property 'test' of non-object, +
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @u_mulder points out, the `test` elements are inside the `suite` element. Additionally, you are trying to access an attribute of the `test` elements, so you must use array notation rather than object notation (see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)). This will work:

```
$robot = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
foreach ($robot->suite->test as $name) {
    echo $name['name'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
[TC000] TEST 000
[TC001] TEST 001
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CuW9X)